# Are Parameters from an URL always strings?

Tags: javascript, rest, typescript

This is a REST Architecture
I have an URL like: http://localhost:8080/api/v1/layout/xyz/9/0/5/0

After I retrieved the data via a Service (typescript) the typeof tells me that I have a String and not a number.

```
@PUT('layout')
    public saveLayout(name: string, @body('Visuals') body, dimX: number, dimY: number, dimWidth: number, dimHeigth: number ) {
        console.log("typeof dimX", typeof(dimX));
        this._wsRA.deleteVOs(name, dimX, dimY, dimWidth, dimHeigth);
    }
```

Did I miss something here? I do not get an error passing the data to the service,I would have expected that I would on if a string goes to a number?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, URL query string params are of type string.

It's up to you to convert them to and from the type you need.

Comment: Thanks, than it dills down to a typescript question. Since, when I do a var dimXnumber = parseInt(dimX);Argument of type 'number' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string'.  Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: Are you trying to convert a number to string? `myNumber.toString()` does it.

Comment: No I get a string and I want to convert to a number. `var dimXnumber = parseInt(dimX);` gives me an error, pls see last post. I just found out that `var dimXnumber = +dimX`works and converts to a number.

Comment: TypeScript's syntax for that is `let dimXnumber: number = parseInt(dimX);`.